# How to prove this problem about doubly periodic?

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions

We say that$ \omega_1$and $\omega_2$ generate the periods of a doubly periodic
function if the periods of the function are precisely the complex
numbers of the form $ m\omega_1+ n\omega_2 $ where m and n are integers. Show that if$ \omega_1$and$ \omega_2$ generate the periods of a doubly periodic function
$f(z)$, and if $\alpha_1$ and $ \alpha_2$are complex numbers, then$\alpha_1 $and $\alpha_2$ generate
the periods of $f (z) $if and only if there is a 2 x 2 matrix  $\mathrm A$with integer
entries and with determinant ±1 such that $A(\omega_1 ,\omega_2) = ( \alpha_1,  \alpha_2  ) $.

I think $ \omega_1 $ and  $\omega_2$ have form  $ m_1\alpha_1 +  n_1 \alpha_2 $，$ m_1$and $ n_1$  are integer .

$\Leftarrow$:
I want to prove   $ \omega_1$and $\omega_2$  have form $ m_1\alpha_1+ n_1\alpha_2 $,i suppose $A= \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end {pmatrix}, \omega_1 =\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ y_1 \\  \end {pmatrix} $and so on. But i can't find this relation.

$\Rightarrow$: i haven't clue.

Comment: If $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ generate the periods, then in particular, they generate $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.  That is, there is an integer matrix $A$ such that  $$\begin{pmatrix}\omega_1\\\omega_2\end{pmatrix}=A
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: But we should  prove $A(\omega_1 ,\omega_2) = ( \alpha_1, \alpha_2 ) $.$(\omega_1 ,\omega_2)$ and $( \alpha_1, \alpha_2 )$ either Column vector or row vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\omega_1,\omega_2$ generate the periods, and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ do as well.

Since $\omega_1,\omega_2$ generate periods, that means any period may be written as an integer combination of them, so in particular $\alpha_1=a_{11}\omega_1+a_{12}\omega_2$ and $\alpha_2=a_{21}\omega_1+a_{22}\omega_2$ for integers $a_{ij}$. That is,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \omega_1 \\ \omega_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Or $\vec{\alpha}=A\vec{\omega}$ for an integer matrix $A$.

How do we know $A$ must have determinant $\pm1$? Well, the same argument works to show $\vec{\omega}=B\vec{\alpha}$ for some integer matrix $B$ ... can you finish from there?

Comment: OK,thanks!use Formula $A^{-1}$=$\frac{A^*}{|A|}$  and $A^{-1}$ is also entire matrix can know $|A|$= ±1.

Comment: The reason $\det A=\pm1$ is because $B=A^{-1}$ is also an integer matrix, and taking determinants of $AB=I$ yields $(\det A)(\det B)=1$ forcing $\det A$ to be $\pm1$.